# Numerical algorithm on different computers - what difference in results is normal?

Tags: numerical-methods, intel-mkl, linear-equation

I implemented a numerical algorithm using a solver library for linear equation systems. When I test it, i get slightly different results on different computers.

I use a bicgstab algorithm with incomplete LU preconditioning. When testing on 2 computers, after about 20 iterations, results (relative error) begin to differ by E-10. Finally, one computer needs several iterations more than the other to converge to an error of E-7.

Both machines use Intel Xeon E-5 processors. Compiler version is the same. Operating systems are different versions of Linux. Versions of Boost and Intel MKL are not necessarily the same.

What I'm wondering now:

1. Is it normal to have slight numerical differences when running such
   an algorithm on different, but similar machines.
2. If it's not ok, what is likely to cause the differences? Where and
   how should I start further investigations?

Comment: I don't think this should happen if the algorithm is deterministic. Everything should stick to the floating point standards.

Comment: You omit to mention whether or not you instruct the compiler to stick to, for example, IEEE arithmetic, and, also important, whether you use the same binary on both computers.  You also omit to mention if you get the same, to the last digit, results on repeated executions of the same program on the same machine.  If these factors vary, then I'm not surprised by the differences you report, nor would I be bothered by them.  Yes, I think it is normal to have small numerical differences in such situations as you describe.